# Python - pandas: create a separate row for each recurrence of a record

Tags: python, pandas

I have date-interval-data with a "periodicity"-column representing how frequent the date interval occurs:

- Weekly: same weekdays every week
- Biweekly: same weekdays every other week
- Monthly: Same DATES every month

Moreover I have a "recurring_until"-column specifying when the recurrence should stop.
What I need to accomplish is:

- creating a separate row for each recurring record until the "recurring_until" has been reached.

What I have:
[image]

What I need:
[image]

I have been trying with various for loops without much success. Here is the sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id':['1','2','3','4'],'from':['5/31/2020','6/3/2020','6/18/2020','6/10/2020'],'to':['6/5/2020','6/3/2020','6/19/2020','6/10/2020'],'periodicity':['weekly','weekly','biweekly','monthly'],'recurring_until':['7/25/2020','6/9/2020','12/30/2020','7/9/2020']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: what `from` and `to` columns are?

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco - from and to reflects the date interval

Comment: I'm not sure about it. Is the first occurrence referring to `from` or `to` column?

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco - I have added pictures to illustrate. Yes the first occurence is from and to

Comment: ok. now I  got it.  tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all preprocess:

```
df.set_index("id", inplace=True)
df["from"], df["to"], df["recurring_until"] = pd.to_datetime(df["from"]), pd.to_datetime(df.to), pd.to_datetime(df.recurring_until)
```

Next compute all the periodic `from`:

```
new_from = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x["from"], x.recurring_until), axis=1) #generate all days between from and recurring_until
new_from[df.periodicity=="weekly"] = new_from[df.periodicity=="weekly"].apply(lambda x:x[::7]) #slicing by week
new_from[df.periodicity=="biweekly"] = new_from[df.periodicity=="biweekly"].apply(lambda x:x[::14]) #slicing by biweek
new_from[df.periodicity=="monthly"] = new_from[df.periodicity=="monthly"].apply(lambda x:x[x.day==x.day[0]]) #selectiong only days equal to the first day
new_from = new_from.explode() #explode to obtain a series
new_from.name = "from" #naming the series
```

after this we have `new_from` like this:

```
id
1   2020-05-31
1   2020-06-07
1   2020-06-14
1   2020-06-21
1   2020-06-28
1   2020-07-05
1   2020-07-12
1   2020-07-19
2   2020-06-03
3   2020-06-18
3   2020-07-02
3   2020-07-16
3   2020-07-30
3   2020-08-13
3   2020-08-27
3   2020-09-10
3   2020-09-24
3   2020-10-08
3   2020-10-22
3   2020-11-05
3   2020-11-19
3   2020-12-03
3   2020-12-17
4   2020-06-10
Name: from, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now lets compute all the periodic `to` as:

```
new_to = new_from+(df.to-df["from"]).loc[new_from.index]
new_to.name = "to"
```

and we have `new_to` like this:

```
id
1   2020-06-05
1   2020-06-12
1   2020-06-19
1   2020-06-26
1   2020-07-03
1   2020-07-10
1   2020-07-17
1   2020-07-24
2   2020-06-03
3   2020-06-19
3   2020-07-03
3   2020-07-17
3   2020-07-31
3   2020-08-14
3   2020-08-28
3   2020-09-11
3   2020-09-25
3   2020-10-09
3   2020-10-23
3   2020-11-06
3   2020-11-20
3   2020-12-04
3   2020-12-18
4   2020-06-10
Name: to, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

We can finally concatenate this two series and join them to the initial dataframe:

```
periodic_df = pd.concat([new_from, new_to], axis=1).join(df[["periodicity", "recurring_until"]]).reset_index()
```

result:

[image]